# Django get a list of parents each populated with their own children

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a pair of parent/children relation models like:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    author = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the serializers are like:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

and finally views:

```py
class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class CommentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

Now I want to created an API that returns a list of `Post`s, in which each `Post` will contain two additional fields, one be `all_comments`, and the other will be `latest_comment`. I understand this could be easily done in SQL using `JOIN`s. I am new to Django. I wonder if there's any easy way to do it in Django. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this config works for you :)

```
class CommentPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # New Serializer class
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ('post',)


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    all_comments = CommentPostSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source='comment_set')
    latest_comment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_latest_comment(self, post):
        latest_comment = post.comment_set.last()
        return CommentPostSerializer(latest_comment).data

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks! `all_comments` works!, but for the latest comments, I got: ValueError: earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta.

Comment: change -> **`post.comment_set.latest('-id')`** (updated the answer)

Comment: oops... my bad... Use **`last()`** instead of `latest` @ElgsQianChen